# How will this C preprocessor be evaluated ?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
int main(){
float s=10,u=30,t=2,a;
a=2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t); // How is this evaluated ? 
printf("Result %f\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

The output displayed by the compiler is -100.000000. But according to me it should be -25.000000. What should i do to correct it and what is my mistake?

Comment: `#define` does a *literal string substitution*. So you'll get `a = 2*(s-u*t)/t*t` which, given operator order of evaluation, will evaluate as, `a = (2*(s-u*t)/t)*t`. You probably really want `a = 2*(s-u*t)/(t*t)` so you should have `#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))`

Comment: FWIW, [see this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: The best way to know: `cpp your_file.c`

Comment: @SouravGhosh I discover that compound literals are, in fact, operators. Wut.

Comment: @Quentin No, i don't think so, we're talking about the _notation_ for compound notation there, I believe. :-)

Comment: This should be noted on every C tutorial. Read one first if you haven't

Comment: @SouravGhosh makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

`#define` does a *literal substitution* of the string of characters you have defined. So the expression:

```
 a = 2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t*t)
```

Will expand to:

```
 a = 2*(s-u*t)/t*t
```

Which, given operator order of evaluation, will evaluate as:

```
a = (2*(s-u*t)/t)*t
```

Not what you want. You probably really want `a = 2*(s-u*t)/(t*t)` so you should have:

```
#define SQUARE(x) (x*x)
```

Or even better, as @Jongware points out, since `x` itself could be an expression:

```
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
```

That way, expressions like, `SQUARE(a+b)` will evaluate properly as `((a+b)*(a+b))`, not `(a+b*a+b)`.

Also as pointed out in comments, you need to beware of macro expression results when you have side effects in your arguments. For example, what does `SQUARE(x++)` do, and what is the value of `x` when it is done? In this case, it would give `(x++)*(x++)`, with the value of `x` being post incremented twice and results may be undefined behavior (depends upon order of post increment in this case).

Comment: Ever so slightly safer: `#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))`. It will remove (only) one further possible pitfall: `SQUARE(1+2)`.

Comment: FYI (well, I guess *you* know – but for others' sake): this *only* removes *one* additional pitfall. It doesn't guard against blatant misuse such as in `SQUARE(x++)`.

Comment: @lurker perhaps reword "literal string substitution" as to avoid vocabulary collisions with "string literal" and the stringification operator.

Comment: @Jongware indeed. Then we're getting into a whole other set of issues. :)

Comment: @Quentin I reworded a little. Not perfect, but perhaps better. It's hard to avoid the word "string" and, thus, a potential confusion. The preprocessor really does a "literal string substitution" as in "a string substitution that is literal" rather than a "substitution of a so-called *string literal*"

Comment: @lurker I've seen "text" and "token" substitution, but your new wording looks unambiguous to me now. Thanks !

Comment: `SQUARE(x++)` results in UB, right? There is no sequence point between the two increments...

Comment: @Kninnug yes, it does. But I'm not addressing that here since that's actually a topic of another question that has appeared many times on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is a text replacement. So your expression becomes:

```
a=2*(s-u*t)/t*t;
```

`*` and `/` have equal precendence, so `2*(s-u*t)` gets divided by `t` then multiplied by `t`.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

The macro function `SQUARE(x) x*x` calculate the square of the given number 'x'.

**Step 1:** float s=10, u=30, t=2, a; Here the variable s, u, t, a are declared as an floating point type and the variable s, u, t are initialized to 10, 30, 2.

**Step 2:** a = 2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t); becomes,

=> a = 2 * (10 - 30 * 2) / t * t; Here SQUARE(t) is replaced by macro to t*t .

=> a = 2 * (10 - 30 * 2) / 2 * 2;

=> a = 2 * (10 - 60) / 2 * 2;

=> a = 2 * (-50) / 2 * 2 ;

=> a = 2 * (-25) * 2 ;

=> a = (-50) * 2 ;

=> a = -100;

**Step 3:** printf("Result=%f", a); It prints the value of variable 'a'.

Hence the output of the program is `-100`

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
int main(){
float s=10,u=30,t=2,a;
a=2*(s-u*t)/t*t; // SQUARE(t) is defined as t*t so it is 
                 // what is placed here instead of SQUARE(t)
```

Which is probably not what you want since `/t*t==1`.

SOLUTION:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
```

then:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
int main(){
float s=10,u=30,t=2,a;
a=2*(s-u*t)/((t)*(t)); // again, exactly as in #define SQUARE(t)
```